# Calculation of PCA Scores in Matlab

Tags: matlab, pca

I'm having trouble understanding how scores are calculated by principal component analysis.

If I perform PCA on a matrix X, by: `[coeff score] = pca(X)`

then should `dot(coeff(1,:) , X(1,:)) = score(1,1)` ?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `Xcentered = score*coeff'`, scores are the eigenvectors. scores are an output of PCA, "how are they calculated" is the same question as "how to program PCA"

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks a lot Ander. Can you tell me how I can apply the coefficients calculated on a training set to a test set please?

Comment: `Xcentered = score*coeff'`. Your `score` is the part that you "trained" (PCA is a mathematical decomposition, I struggle to define it as a machine learning tool), and the coefficients are what are individual to your sample. So a new "test" set (after removing the mean) is a new `Xcentered`, so you need to solve the above equation for `coeff` ;) hopefully not too hard

Comment: Excellent . Thanks Ander. So, centering is always done by subtracting the mean of each variable? Also, I assume I'd use the means calculated on the training set?

Comment: Centering is done by substracting the mean of your "training" data. The mean should be the same size as 1 sample. Use that mean, do not recompute a new one with new data. PCA is a mathematical decomposition that looks for variance in the data, and there is no variance in the mean. But if you change the mean, then you may introduce mistakes that look like variance, but they are not.

Comment: Yes. That makes sense. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I used in case it helps anyone:

```
[coeff,score,latent,tsquared,explained,mu] = pca(training);
testCentered = test;

for i = 1:size(testCentered,2)
    testCentered(:,i) = test(:,i)  - mean(training(:,i));  
end

testScore = testCentered*inv(coeff');
```